# How many different tangent angles create reducible expressions like $\tan(60^\circ)=\sqrt3$?

Tags: trigonometry

How many different tangent angles create reducible expressions like $\tan(60^\circ)=\sqrt3$? Please include obscure angles. Where would information like this be found? There are in infinite number of degree steps to be considered. How to address this problem?

Comment: What precisely do you mean by reducible?

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_constants_expressed_in_real_radicals)?

Comment: If the trig angle can be expressed  as a polynomial, then it is often solvable. 
 Example as $\cos(\theta) = -\cos(2\theta)$ which is $\cos(\theta) + 2\cos(\theta)^2 - 1 = 0$ has a solution $\theta = 60 \text{ degrees}$, and solving for $\cos(\theta)$ gives you the radical value.

Comment: @user222031 yes very much like that. Is that exhaustive?

Comment: @DanielV that is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%27s_theorem

Comment: @Dale  Then, the answer is that, for infinitely (but countably) many angles $\theta \in \mathbb{Q}\pi \cap \left(-\frac{\pi}{2},+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$, $\tan(\theta)$ can be expressed via radicals.  However, if you require that $\theta$ is of the form $\frac{p}{q}\pi$ for some rational numbers $\frac{p}{q}\in\left(-\frac12,+\frac12\right)$ with fixed $q\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$, then I would suggest that you look at $q=2^r F_1F_2\cdots F_s$ where $r$ is a nonnegative integer and $F_1,\ldots,F_s$ are distinct Fermat primes.

Comment: @Batominovski I would accept that as the answer if you would kindly paste it there. Are you saying that Fermat prime numbers are directly related to the radicals found in the tangent function? Also, is there a reason you included 8 Fermat primes?

Comment: It is known that the trigonometric functions of an integer number of degrees may be expressed by radicals if the number of degrees is divisible by 3: https://www.mapleprimes.com/posts/144188-Trigonometric-Functions-In-Radicals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For infinitely (but countably) many angles $\theta\in\mathbb{Q}\pi\cap\left(-\frac\pi2,+\frac\pi2\right)$, the number $\tan(\theta)$ can be expressed via radicals in the sense of the link given by user222031 in a comment above. However, if you require that $\theta$ is of the form $\frac{p}{q}\pi$ for some rational numbers $\frac{p}{q}\in\left(−\frac12,+\frac12\right)$ with a fixed denominator $q\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$, then I would suggest that you look at $q=2^rf_1f_2\cdots f_s$, where $r$ and $s$ are nonnegative integers, and $f_1,f_2,\ldots,f_s$ are pairwise distinct Fermat primes.  Only such values of $q$ offer a nontrivial number of $p$ satisfying the required property.  (For *most* $q$, the only $p$ that works is $p=0$.)  This is due to a theorem by Gauss (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_polygon)).

**P.S.:**  By "most $q$," I lied.  The natural density of $q$ with more than one working value of $p$ is somewhere (strictly) between $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{3}{4}$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2522482/also-is-there-a-programming-language-that-can-easily-tell-of-a-number-is-a-radi